# I was trying to set wallpaper in android mobile using ionic

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic need some help to set wallpaper in android using ionic app.
Its is basically like if I click on any image I must get a pop up to set as wallpaper and if I click yes it will change my mobiles wallpaper.

Here is my code `homepage.html`

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
   <ion-header collapse="condense">
         <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title size="large">Blank</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
   </ion-header>
<img (click)="setwallpaper" src="../../assets/11_nasaspacescapes_0005_6.jpg">
<img src="../../assets/11bradfieldpark1920x1200.jpg">
<img src="../../assets/11castle_germany_de1.jpg">
<img src="../../assets/11coralreefpattern1920x1200.jpg">
<img src="../../assets/11dualorbs.jpg">
<img src="../../assets/11lightning11.jpg">
<img src="../../assets/11nickboyerart-witheredflower1.jpg">
<img src="../../assets/11qingzang.jpg">
<img src="../../assets/11royalalberthall1920x1200.jpg">

</ion-content>
```

And here is my `home-page.ts` file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  setwallpaper(url){
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      window.plugins.wallpaper.setImage(url);
      console.log('Success setting wallpaper.');
    });
  }
  constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: You are Doing it wrong.

Comment: Please help me im new in ionic and stuck badly here

Comment: Change your Function in html `(click)="setwallpaper(YourImageSrc)"`

Comment: tried but getting a new error like platform not declared and plugin not declared

Comment: you have to import `Platform` and `Plugin`. Please take some Tutorials on Ionic then do this.